# Why is response body in golang is a readCloser?

Tags: http, go

I'm wondering how http package in golang works. I can see that the body of http response is like this:

```
type Response struct {
    StatusCode int
    Header     Header
    Body       io.ReadCloser
}
```

The `Body` is a ReadCloser. Why is that?

The main question is: Does http package read header and body at the same time and completely and then returns the `Response` or it just reads the `Header` part and when we are reading from `Body` we are actually reading from a connection? Is it possible that we encounter an error before we finish the whole body(e.g because connection drops)? or the body is completely received and resides in the memory when we get the response?

Comment: How would the http package handle a very large response if it had to read it all before giving you the headers? How would it work if the body streamed indefinitely? The Body is a Reader, because that is what is expected from the protocol.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

> The Body is a ReadCloser. Why is that?

Because you can Read from it and you have to Close it once you are done.

> The main question is: Does http package read header and body at the same time and completely and then returns the Response [?]

No.

> or it just reads the Header part and when we are reading from Body we are actually reading from a connection?

Yes

> Is it possible that we encounter an error before we finish the whole body(e.g because connection drops)?

Yes.

> or the body is completely received and resides in the memory when we get the response?

No. Think of a 4.5 TByte stream.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your response. Just for the sake of completeness, can you also provide some reference for your answers?(e.g. link to documentation or some part of the implementation code, ...)  I upvoted your answer and I will accept the answer as soon as you provide some references.

Comment: @samadmontazeri, I don't quite follow your request for this additional info. The docs fix the behavior, not the implementation. The implementation is in the source code (which is freely available—right in the `src` directory of your Go installation), and may change in any way even between point releases of Go. The source code of the `net/http` package located in `src/net/http`.

Comment: @samadmontazeri, please also note that the implementation of the body reader is complicated—while Volker is correct in that `net/http.Response.Body`'s implementation "reads from the socket", it's not done directly—there are several software layers at play. Also note that the actual reading code depends on the HTTP protocol version used (HTTP2 is very different from HTTP 1.x) and is even different between "fixed length" response in HTTP 1.x and "continous", which uses a special body encoding called "chunking"…

Comment: @samadmontazeri, …Add to that that the `net/http` package transparently handles any so-called "transfer encoding" between its client and the server (which is completely transparent to the client), and can also transparently handle content encoding, if it's not explicitly controlled by the client. In other words, it'd be best if you 1) read up more on how HTTP works; 2) augment that knowledge with reading the `net/http` package's source code.

Comment: @kostix Thanks for very interesting info and good suggestions.

Comment: @samadmontazeri, "chunked", not "chunking". Well, and you might start right [here](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc7230)—it's actually quite easy to follow. One more point which may be interesting for you: here at my $dayjob, we're using continuous HTTP responses (those with unknown length) to transfer real-time data between the clients. In such cases there's just no concept of "completely read request body" because it's being read as long as the server and client are up and connected.